# Why is my Jquery autocomplete not working on my search bar?

Tags: python, jquery, django, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have a search bar that should be visible in all my pages in django, however the autocomplete is not working.

my base.html has the following:

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

this is my search bar:

```
  <div class="sbar ">
    <div class="row-search ">
        <div class="col-6">
            <form action="{% url 'search' %}" method="get">
                <div class="input-size input-group mb-3">
                  <input type="text" name="q" id="searchBox" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
                  <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
                  <div id="search-suggestions-dropdown"></div>  <!-- Add this line -->
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

this is my script inside my base.html:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#searchBox').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                console.log("Making AJAX request with query:", request.term);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{% url 'search' %}",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: {
                        'q': request.term
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log("Received data:", data);
                        var suggestions = [];
                        data.forEach(function(item) {
                            suggestions.push({
                                label: item.label,
                                value: item.value
                            });
                        });
                        response(suggestions);
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                console.log("Selected item:", ui.item);
                window.location.href = ui.item.value;
            }
        });
    });
  </script>
```

this is from my views.py:

```
class SearchView(View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        query = request.GET.get('q')
        print("Received query:", query)  # Print the received query
        if query:
            infos = Info.objects.filter(Q(firstName__icontains=query) | Q(
                middleName__icontains=query) | Q(lastName__icontains=query))
            files = Files.objects.filter(fileName__icontains=query)
            results = list(infos.values('firstName', 'middleName', 'lastName',
                           'orphanID')) + list(files.values('fileName', 'fileID'))
            results = [
                {
                    'label': item['firstName'] + ' ' + item['middleName'] + ' ' + item['lastName'] if 'firstName' in item else item['fileName'],
                    'value': item['firstName'] + ' ' + item['middleName'] + ' ' + item['lastName'] if 'firstName' in item else item['fileName'],
                }
                for item in results
            ]
            print("Infos:", infos)
            print("Files:", files)
            print("Results:", results)
            return JsonResponse(results, safe=False)
        print("No query received")  # Print a message when no query is received
        return JsonResponse({}, status=400)
```

this is my test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Search Bar</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="#" method="get">
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input type="text" name="q" id="searchBox" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
        </div>
    </form>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#searchBox').on('click', function() {
            console.log("Search bar clicked");
        });

        $('#searchBox').autocomplete({
            source: function(request, response) {
                console.log("Making AJAX request with query:", request.term);
                // Mock AJAX request
                setTimeout(function() {
                    var data = [
                        { label: "Result 1", value: "Result 1" },
                        { label: "Result 2", value: "Result 2" }
                    ];
                    console.log("Received data:", data);
                    var suggestions = [];
                    data.forEach(function(item) {
                        suggestions.push({
                            label: item.label,
                            value: item.value
                        });
                    });
                    response(suggestions);
                }, 1000);
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function(event, ui) {
                console.log("Selected item:", ui.item);
                // Prevent the form from being submitted
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me where the error is? There are already console print statements but they do not show up when i type in the search bar. I tried a test.html and the autocomplete is working there. I want to be able to search thru my models using the searchbox.

Comment: You've placed several `console.log()` and `print()` statements within your code.  It might help us troubleshoot if we knew what the outcomes of those are.  Second, you stated that the autocomplete worked in test.html.  Can we see that file?

Comment: @raphael i updated my question to include the test.html. Also for the print statements, they're not showing up, there's no jquery/ajax related outputs in the network/console , thats why i can never solve the problem. But i know the search works because it gives results after pressing enter. But the autocomplete for my dropdown isnt.

Comment: You're mocking the ajax request in your test file, so apparently, your ajax request doesn't succeed. Are you sure you're getting a success?

Comment: @Shrimp yes im sure, the test file was just to make sure that the jquery ui is working on my browser. I tried it and its doing the autocomplete when i type in the search bar.